# Trouble signing in with Devise - JSON.stringify escaping characters

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm having trouble signing users with Devise because of the format of the credentials that get sent to the `users/sign_in` route. Here's my client side code for sending the request:

```
  async function handleSubmit() {
    const bodyFormData = new FormData();
    bodyFormData.append('user', JSON.stringify(credentials));

    try {
      const res = await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: url,
        data: bodyFormData,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
      });
      console.log('Status: ', res.status);
      setSignedIn(true);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.toJSON());
    }
  }
```

And here's the server response:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2020-08-22 18:12:55 -0700
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"{\"email\":\"fake@email.com\",\"password\":\"password\"}"=>"[FILTERED]"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 170)
```

As you can see, `JSON.stringify` is unnecessarily escaping characters. When I send a request with Postman, it works fine:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2020-08-22 17:44:37 -0700
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"fake@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", "fake@email.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 200 OK in 269ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms | Allocations: 4545)
```

Comment: It looks like your credentials are in JSON format, if so, why are you trying to stringify it and then send it as form data? You can send it as JSON(as it is) to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set content type to json if that's how you want to send your data

```
const res = await axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: url,
  data: credentials,
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
});
```

Or just append the form data normally without using JSON.stringify, but I think you'll have better luck with something like this:

```
bodyFormData.append('user[username]', credentials.username);
bodyFormData.append('user[password]', credentials.password);
```